# How to create random Gaussian vector in c++?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to figure out how to generate a random Gaussian vector in c++. Would it be sufficient to generate random gaussian numbers and putting them in a vector?

Comment: You need to explain what you mean by a Gaussian vector.  There are at least three different interpretations of these words I can think of.

Comment: Which definition of "vector" do you want us to use? The C++ definition or the mathematical one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Boost.Random](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_random.html) includes a normal distribution generator. You should be able to use this to populate a vector. Complete tested example code:

```
#include <boost/random/random_device.hpp>
#include <boost/random/normal_distribution.hpp>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    boost::random::random_device rng;
    boost::random::normal_distribution<> generator(0, 100);
    std::vector<int> vec;

    vec.reserve(100);
    std::generate_n(
        std::back_inserter(vec),
        100,
        [&] () { return generator(rng); });

    for (auto i : vec)
        std::cout << i << ',';

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** I just realized you were, probably, talking about multivariate Gaussian distribution. In this case, I think, you'd need *N* normal distributions, each corresponding to an univariate distribution along one of the coordinates. Then, you generate **random vector**'s coordinates by sampling each of the distributions. Effectively, the edited code below represents *coordinates of 10 two-dimensional **random vectors***, using C++11 pseudo-random number generation ([code on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/3OWsra)). Note, in the example given there will be correlation between the two coordinates, since there is correlation between consecutive pseudo-random numbers. One can try using two seeds with two generators with more sophisticated algorithms provided by the Standard library. However, I feel, there still might be a correlation, even using two different generators - one would have to investigate this issue to give a definite answer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <iomanip>

int main() 
{
 std::random_device device_random_;
 std::default_random_engine generator_(device_random_());
 std::normal_distribution<> distribution_x_(1.0, 0.5);
 std::normal_distribution<> distribution_y_(10.0, 1.0);

 std::vector<double> vector_x_, vector_y_;

 for (int counter_(0); counter_ < 10; ++counter_)
 {
  vector_x_.push_back(distribution_x_(generator_));
  vector_y_.push_back(distribution_y_(generator_));
  std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(4) << "(" << vector_x_[counter_] 
            << ", " << vector_y_[counter_] << ")\n";
 }

 return (0);
}
```

Program output:

```
(0.2390, 10.3887)
(1.1087, 9.5847)
(1.0920, 9.3468)
(1.1982, 11.6633)
(0.8840, 11.0903)
(0.5573, 8.5121)
(0.6709, 11.4706)
(1.1477, 9.4374)
(0.8778, 11.0323)
(0.8255, 9.7704)
```